# Finding the week number of the quarter in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, date, vba

I need a VBA function that will return the week number in a quarter from a given date.

For example, 
Input of 1/1/2016 will return 1,
1/4/2016 will return 2,
10/1/2016 will return 1,
10/7/2016 will return 2,
11/11/2016 will return 7

I have a function in Excel that does this:

```
=IF(O48="","",WEEKNUM(O48)-WEEKNUM(LOOKUP(O48,DATE(YEAR(O48),{1,4,7,10},1)))+1)
```

But I am struggling to port it to VBA.  Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DatePart` to get the week number in the year, then subtract 13 weeks for each quarter (also available with the `DatePart` function):

```
Public Function WeekOfQuarter(inValue As Date)
    WeekOfQuarter = DatePart("ww", inValue) - ((DatePart("q", inValue) - 1) * 13)
End Function
```